# Passing non sequential columns in a range in VBA to create dynamic charts

Tags: vba, excel

I am a newbie to VBA and was trying to create a dynamic range for simple trendline chart, initially to access the components , I recorded a Macro while creating the chart so that I can edit the source range later to be altered dynamically

```
Sub Macro10()
'
' Macro10 Macro
'
    Range("B8").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineStacked).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet10!$B$8:$C$16808")

    'ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet6!$B$8:$C$16808")
End Sub
```

My source data is in separately sheet(Sheet6)and I want to refer it dynamically to build my chart, In source data the required columns are not next to each other, 
so I was trying to alter the Range (in the commented Source Range) to refer to those  columns, any ideas on how to achieve it ?

Also I need it to be dynamic for both the columns which I want to pass in the range to build a time series kind of chart.

I tried using one of the answers mentioned below, but my chart was not proper , does the CuurentRegion Property select all the columns or only the relevant columns

```
 data.


Sub Macro10()
'
' Macro10 Macro
'

'



    Dim R As Range

    Set R = Sheet6.Range("C1").CurrentRegion 'Dates for Time Series
    Set R = Union(R, Sheet6.Range("F1").CurrentRegion) ' Profits for those Dates

    'Range("B8").Select
    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    'ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineStacked).Select
    'ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet10!$B$8:$C$16808")
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
     ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=R

    'ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet6!$B$8:$C$16808")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with Selection is generally not a good approach. Build your cell selection in a range variable instead.

```
Dim R as Range
Set R = Range("B8", Range("B8").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
Set R = Union(R, Range("A1:A9")
Set R = Union(R, Range("X1:X9")
```

Now you can pass your range like this:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=R
```

Comment: hey can you please take a look now on the edit I made

Comment: I don't think CurrentRegion will help you. First step is to be able to define a simple range in code. Once you can do that, you can merge several of them together as I showed above. See edited example above

Comment: Range("B8", Range("B8").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)) , here xlToRight will also select column C, in my case I have Order Dates in column B and Profits in Column D, so would this still work ?

Comment: There are a LOT of ways to pick your range. Picking all of B and C, starting from B8 would be Range("B8", Range("C8").End(xlDown))

Comment: Hey Sam , how can I use it to pick columns which are not next to each other ?

Comment: With Union. Create a range for the first column, and with Union you join it with the second column